# How can I get printf to produce "+ 123" instead of " +123"?

Tags: shell, printf, sign, gnu-coreutils, format-string

I want to print a number with a certain field width for the digits, have the digits right-aligned, and print a sign indicator - not right before the digits, but rather before the spacing. Thus

```
$ magic -123 7 
-   123
```

rather than

```
$ magic -123 7 
   -123
```

Can I do that with the GNU coreutils version of the printf utility? Other versions of it perhaps?

**Note:** To be clear, the solution should work for any field spacing and any value, e.g.:

- There might be zero, one or many spaces
- The number might "overflow" the specified width

Comment: just transform the output.

Comment: Can you add some sample inputs with your expected outputs?

Comment: Esp. what should be the output of `magic -123567 4`?

Comment: @anubhava: Obviously no spaces, just `-123567`; the only change is where the spaces are placed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply transform the output:

```
printf %+d 12 | sed 's/[+-]/\0 /'
+ 12
```

Comment: Ooh, slightly neater than mine (now deleted)

Comment: @einpoklum I think this answer gives you enough to work with: do what formatting you can with `printf` then massage it further with a regex. You should not need SO's help to craft you a regex that (for example) converts `.....-12345...` into `-.....12345...`  (dots for spaces for demonstration purposes)

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, I do not believe that you can, with the GNU coreutils version of the `printf`, have space padding be inserted between the sign character and the nonzero digits of the number. `printf` seems to always group the sign with the unpadded digits, placing any additional space padding to the left of the sign.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function called `magic` like this using pure shell utilities:

```
magic() {
   # some sanity checks to make sure you get $1 and $2
   [[ $2 -lt 0 ]] && printf "-" || printf "+"
   printf "%${1}s\n" "${2#[+-]}"
}
```

Now use it as:

```
$> magic 5 120
+  120
$> magic 5 120234
+120234
$> magic 5 -120234
-120234
$> magic 5 -120
-  120
$> magic 5 1
+    1
$> magic 5 +120
+  120
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @KarolyHorvath's suggestion, I suppose this should work:

```
printf "%+7d" 123 | sed -r 's/^( *)([+-])/\2\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
magic () { 
    local sign="+" number=$1 width=$2
    if ((number < 0)); then
        sign="-"
        ((number *= -1))
    fi
    printf '%s%*d\n' "$sign" "$((width - 1))" "$number"
}
```

or

```
magic () {
    printf '%+*d\n' "$2" "$1" | sed -r 's/^( *)([+-])/\2\1/'
}
```

Uses the `*` in the format specification to take the field width from the arguments.